# How to concatenate files in different directories together into a string array

Tags: c#, directory

C# Newbie question, I need to collect files from four folders based on a filter and put them all into one array:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(DirPath, Dts.Variables["User::vCSV_Folder_File_Filter_1"].Value.ToString());
string[] files = string[] + Directory.GetFiles(DirPath, Dts.Variables["User::vCSV_Folder_File_Filter_2"].Value.ToString());
string[] files = string[] + Directory.GetFiles(DirPath, Dts.Variables["User::vCSV_Folder_File_Filter_3"].Value.ToString());
string[] files = string[] + Directory.GetFiles(DirPath, Dts.Variables["User::vCSV_Folder_File_Filter_4"].Value.ToString());
```

What is the best way to do this with c#, somehow concatenate the string first then put into array.

Comment: `List<string> files;` `files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(...));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put *Linq* `Concat`:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 string[] files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(DirPath, Dts.Variables["User::vCSV_Folder_File_Filter_1"].Value.ToString())
   .Concat(Directory.EnumerateFiles(DirPath, Dts.Variables["User::vCSV_Folder_File_Filter_2"].Value.ToString()))
   .Concat(Directory.EnumerateFiles(DirPath, Dts.Variables["User::vCSV_Folder_File_Filter_3"].Value.ToString()))
   .Concat(Directory.EnumerateFiles(DirPath, Dts.Variables["User::vCSV_Folder_File_Filter_4"].Value.ToString())) 
   .ToArray();
```

If you have a collections of `folders` and `filters` and you want to obtain files in *all* `folders` with *all* `filters`, you can use *Cartesian Join* (which can implemented with a help of `SelectMany`):

```
  using System.Linq;

  ... 

  // I've put arrays here, but any collection 
  // which implements IEnumerable<string> will do
  string[] folders = ...
  string[] filters = ...

  string[] files = folders
    .SelectMany(folder => filters
       .SelectMany((filter) => Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, filter))) 
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Many Thanks Dmitry above works perfectly and a nice clean simple answer.

Answer (score -2):

If the filter you have mentioned is fixed and it is in the same just the ending number is different, i would personally do it using `for` loop.

```
const int noOfFilters = 4;
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(DirPath,Dts.Variables["User::vCSV_Folder_File_Filter_1"].Value.ToString());
for(int i = 2; i <= noOfFilters  /*using the variables helps minimal change*/;i++)
{
    files = files  + Directory.GetFiles(DirPath, Dts.Variables["User::vCSV_Folder_File_Filter_" + i.ToString()].Value.ToString());
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `string[] + Directory.GetFiles(...)` doesn't compile

Comment: @DmitryBychenko sorry for the typo